# How to disable gray animation from center to edges on bottom navigation on tap

Tags: android, animation, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

Having reviewed a lot of material, I still did not find a solution. As you can see on git below, when you tap on the botton navigation icon, it has gray animation from the center to the edges. Is there a way to disable this animation?

[Gray animation](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*ru89Jnj0ObDXthynZMZrdw.gif)
Here's my XML

```xml
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottomNavigationIconColor"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_item_text_color_state"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
```

and nav_item_text_color_state

```xml
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_checked="false"
        android:color="@color/bottomNavigationIconColor" />
    <item
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:color="#005EFF" />
</selector>
```

**Update**
Found solution to this. To disable this gray ripple effect just add  `app:itemBackground="@null"` to xml.

Comment: provide your code or xml file

Answer (score 5):

Found solution to this, just add  `app:itemBackground="@null"` to xml.

Answer (score 5):

Use `app:itemRippleColor="@color/your_color"` to set your custom color for tap effect or `app:itemRippleColor="@null"` for no effect

Comment: this is wrong answer

Answer (score 4):

Set app:itemBackground to null doesn't work now.

The new way is:

```
app:itemBackground="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the codes above worked for me. If that's the case for you too, try this:

```
app:itemActiveIndicatorStyle="@null"
app:itemBackground="@android:color/transparent"
```